# How to compare the efficiency of different layouts?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Currently I am running into a performance issue, with one of my activitys.

In this Activity I am inflating a lot.
So beside optimizing the code I would like to optimize the layout, too.

The basic ideas are clear (avoid nesting, flat hirachie, viewStub where usefull, merge for the basic frame, ...). But still at some points you have to choose (like do I use a relative layout or a linear layout, a table layout or even a gridlayout).

Here is where my questions fit in:
How do I compare the efficiency of differend ways (that are giving me a similar layout)?

What I am already doing is to check the layout with the `Hierarchy View`, which gives me a general idea, which parts of the layout are expensive and which aren't.

**BUT:**
It does not give me an accurate comparission between different ways to do one thing. One and the same layout inflation can vary between 1ms and 20ms, even if it is the same layout only at a different time.

So my question: How do I compare different ways to achieve a layout for their efficiency, regardless of external circumstances?

Comment: Heh sounds to me like you have faaar to many views :). Answering this question is pretty hard. You can do tests but they will vary so you have to do statistic tests (many tests) on several devices and before you get started you will have wasted your life.

Comment: roughly 350 Views according to the hierarchy viewer. But to your comment, shouldn't be a layout that is effective on one device (in general) be effective on other devices too?

Comment: Yes it should, but you never know for sure with android, but you still have to test your different layout approaches multiple times and do some statistics in order to find the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [layoutopt](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/layoutopt.html) tool for the layout optimization.

If the view layout optimized enough then at runtime creating more views with the same layout should be optimized.